# How to use nuxt 2 and tailwind 2 in the same time?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I try to use vuejs 2 syntax on my nuxt 2 project and wanna use tailwind 2 because vuejs 2 only support tailwind 2. When i try setup nuxt 2 project, it require postcss 8.0 but tailwind 2 require postcss 7.0. what should i do now.

I want to use vuejs 2 syntax on nuxt 2 project and tailwind css 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following setup for your package.json file

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^3.15.1",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.1",
 "postcss": "^8.2.8",
 "prettier": "^2.3.2",
 "sass": "^1.37.5",
 "sass-loader": "10.1.1"
}
```

This will work fine, I have a project currently running with this setup